# ListView inside a ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-layout, android-listview

I have researched a lot regarding this topic and I'm finally posting this question cause I did not find what I searched for.

I have a layout with Listview inside a ScrollView.

Listview is used to **display the comments** from various users.
The layout is as follows :

**Layout.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/panel_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/image" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/image_divider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                android:background="#c2c2c2" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prod_name_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image_divider"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="SUV car by Nissaan"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productCost_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/prod_name_text"
                android:layout_below="@+id/prod_name_text"
                android:text="$150"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/likes_details_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/prod_name_text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/productCost_text"
                android:text="rob + 1,124"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dreamitBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/likes_details_text"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/dreamplus" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addtoListBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/likes_details_text"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dreamitBtn"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/add_to_list_bg" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/_first_divider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addtoListBtn"
                android:background="#838B8B" />

            <TabHost
                android:id="@+id/tabHost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/_first_divider"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </TabWidget>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cost"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/addtoListBtn"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addtoListBtn"
                android:background="@drawable/buy_button"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="60$"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/second_divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#838B8B" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comments_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/upper_divider"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comments_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comments_count"
                android:text="Comment(s)"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/upper_divider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/comments_text"
                android:background="#000000" /> 

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/upper_divider"
                 >
            </ListView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/lower_divider"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/comments_edit"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lower_divider"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:hint="Enter your comment"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/post_button"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lower_divider"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comments_edit"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="Post" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And the layout looks like :

So the layout consists of three parts : (Thick Grey Line acts as a divider)

**First Part :**

[image: Screen 1]

Includes Webservice call for image and cost,product name and users etc.

**Second Part :**

[image: Screen 2]

Has 3 tabs where all the tabs content will be retrieved from single web service.

**Third Part :**

[image: Screen 3]

This is where the **actual listview exists** but it fails to show. The **edit text** at the bottom is actually **below the listview** which fails to show up. This also includes a web service call.

I have added a **header to listview.**

**Solutions that I have tried so far :**

I have used a helper class to set the height of Listview dynamically(atleast thats what I think it does) :

The class is as follows :

```
public class Helper {

    public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();

        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            // do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        // set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = myListView.getPaddingBottom() + myListView.getPaddingTop();

        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
                listItem.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        }   
        // setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        System.out.println("List view id: "+myListView.getId());


            params.height = totalHeight
                    + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter
                            .getCount() - 1));
            System.out.println("The params height is " + params.height);
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        // print height of adapter on log
        Log.i("height of listItem:", String.valueOf(totalHeight));
    }

}
```

And I have called this as

```
Helper.getListViewSize(MainActivity.listView);
```

after setting the adapter to list.

**Second Solution:**

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

From what I read,this syncs the scrollview according to listview.

**Web Service Call :**

I am calling the webservice for comments as soon as the above layout launches. I can see the web service being called as I can see the response printed in the logcat. But it does not set the listview.

**Note :**

I have implemented the webservice call of listview separately and it works and sets the comments to the listview. So, the real problem exists with the fact that I have used scrollview inside a listview.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had this same issue, I followed: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/03/android-listview-into-scrollview-issue.html and was able to achieve what I needed (which seems like what you need as well).

Answer (score 1):

ListView inside a ScrollView is not a good practice because listview has it own scrolling if it doesnt fit on the screen.

Comment: I know it is a bad practice but I am need of this. How will I achieve it ? Any ideas ?

Comment: you can give weight to the list view and editext that are inside your scrollview and then you can disable the touch for scrollview when touch is in the listview.